# Is there any kind of help for people who want to start a stake pool?

Tags: stake-pool

I would like to set up a stake pool but I have seen that with less than 800k - 1 million ADA it is not profitable. I would like to know if there is any kind of help for those modest pools that want to start with this type of structure to overcome the first months of life and cover the costs of servers until marketing and advertising do their job. Thank you very much.

Comment: I’m voting to close this question because it feels more like a discussion - if you have questions on how to start a stake pool, ask that. This site is a great resource for learning about Cardano but it's not intended to be used to find others to pool up with.

Answer (score 2):

You can apply for support from the Cardano Foundation here. https://iohk.io/en/blog/posts/2021/04/01/announcing-a-new-round-of-community-stake-pool-delegation/

These happen quarterly, there's no guarantee that you'll get it, but it's worth a shot, especially if the mission and vision of your stakepool aligns with that of the foundation.

**Edit.**

It seems the form is closed, but I'd suggest keeping an eye out for the next round of delegations.

Answer (score 0):

Indeed if you do not have a good amount of delegated ADAs in your pool you will not be able to create blocks with which you will not receive rewards. In fact, some pools have left the cardano network because it did not pay them to keep BP and Relays without the possibility of receiving any reward after months. It is a task that you should take as a business, look for people who want to delegate their ADAs in your pool and make your economic and time investment. Good luck!